# Splitting a string containing <if> <else> with regexps

Tags: php, regex, string

I'm very poor with regexps but this should be very simple for someone who knows regexps.

Basically I will have a string like this:

```
<if>abc <else>xyz
```

I would like a regexp so if the string contains `<if> <else>`, it splits the string into two parts and returns the two strings after `<if>` and `<else>`. In the above example it might return an array with the first element being `abc`, second `xyz`. I'm open to approaches not using regexps too.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
// $subject is you variable containing string you want to run regex on
$result = preg_match('/<if>(.*)<else>(.*)/i', $subject, $matches);

// $matches[0] has the full matched text
// $matches[1] has if part
// $matches[2] has else part
```

The `/i` at the end makes the search case sensitive to allow both `<if><else>`  and `<IF> <elSE>`

Comment: Do I need to set $matches with `$matches=array();` before calling this? What will happen if the string doesn't contain <if> <else> and I try to access $matches after calling this line?

Comment: To answer my own question above, $matches is set to just an empty array() if the `<if> <else>` isn't found

Answer (score 1):

Regular Expressions will work for this in simple cases. For more complicated cases (where nesting occurs), you may find it easier to parse the string and use a simple stack to grab the data you need.

Answer (score 0):

The regular expression you are looking for is:

```
/<if>(.*)<\/else>(.*)/
```

You'd have a problem if there are multiple `<else>`'s, though. It can be edited depending on what you want the result to be.

Also note that this regular expression would work even if there is something before `<if>`.

In PHP, you'd want a code like the following:

```
<?php
$string = '<if>abc</else>xyz';
preg_match_all("/<if>(.*)<\/else>(.*)/", $string, $matches);
foreach($matches[0] as $value) 
  {
    echo $value;
  }
?>
```

Comment: You have to escape `/` near else